# How to return a list of Screen Names with TwitteR in R

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using the R packing TwitteR to mine tweets from Twitter. I have been trying to use the following search command to get a list of tweets.

```
 test<-searchTwitter("Obama OR california",n = 50)
```

This code works and returns an object that contains the text of the tweet and has 17 other fields within it. But I have been unable to access the field that gives the screen name associated with each tweet.

I think the code I need to use is something like this:

```
test$getScreenName()
```

but I cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello `getScreenName` method is to be used on a single tweet like this :

```
test[[1]]$getScreenName()
```

For all the screenname you can do like this :

```
lapply(1:length(test), function(i) test[[i]]$getScreenName())
# or
sapply(test, function(x) x$getScreenName())
```

Or you can transform `test` to a `data.frame` for a more friendly use :

```
test.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(test, as.data.frame))
```

And acces the screenName like this :

```
test.df$screenName
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this and it worked great! So the reason why I need to do this is to return a list of twitter accounts so I can get a list of who each account follows. I know I can use the getfriends command but would i just use the sapply thing to do it in mass??

Comment: You can try `lapply(yourScreenNames, function(x) getUser(user=x)$getFriends())` but if you have a lot of screenNames most likely you will have the 429 error due to too many request.